# Ignore traling blank cells in chart in Excel

Tags: excel, windows, charts

I want to make a template worksheet with values and `charts` so I can easily just paste data to excel and the `chart` to be ready. But there is one problem, I can't make the `chart` to ignore the `TRALING blank cells`. If the `chart` does not ignore `TRAILING blank cells` the graph becomes small and hard to see, so I must manually reduce the range that the chart is drawing.

Here is an example:[image: This image shows the effect in chart for Column 2 if I don't reduce the range]

Is there a way to ignore the trailing blank spaces in such way? I know I can ignore blank spaces between two values and joining them with a line, I am already using that in my charts.

Comment: I don't think that that will work, becaue I will lose information from other columns. In this case If I hide columns in order to make Column 2 look good I will loose information in Column 1. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes I tried it. It does fix Column 2, but It removes the values in chart for Column 1. Even if I chose "Show values in hidden cells" it fixes Column 1, but again Column 2 looks small.

Comment: Didn't work again. Same result as empty cell.

Comment: Well a) and c) aren't a good decision, since it takes much time to adjust manually the charts. b) sounds good but I don't seem to find a way to do that. As I see it, I can only put the data vertically(as now) or horizontally, since I am working with a grid, both ways I will get the same result. 

I was thinking if there is a function that can return a range of cells, this way I can put an if statement in that function so I could filter the unnecessary cells. But I haven't found such function in excel.

Comment: Yes, this looks really good. I managed to make a dynamic range with the OFFSET function and it works really good, BUT only in one sheet. In order to use the `OFFSET` function in a chart, I must use the `Name Manager` to define name for my `OFFSET` funciton. But when I `copy` my sheet, the name that I've created in the `Name Manager` still refers to Sheet1 and I can't seem to make it work with different sheets. I must declare the name for each sheet. Mybe it will be kind of solution, but time will show. Thank you, @pnuts